# How can export async functions in handlebars?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the discord api with my site but what is cleanest way to use my acyno function  inside my handlebars files ?
The code i want to export :

```
passport.use(new DiscordStrategy({
    clientID: '',
    clientSecret: '',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/app/discord/callback',
    scope: scopes
}, async function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    try {
        // First check if a user with the same email exists
        let user = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email })
        // Check if a user with the same discord ID exists
        if (!user) user = await User.findOne({ discordId: profile.id })
       console.log(`Avatar : ${profile.avatar} \nUsername: ${profile.username}\nID: ${profile.id}`)
        if (user) {
            // A user was found
            if (user.discordId !== profile.id) {
                // Store the discord ID in the database
                user.discordId = profile.id
                await user.save()
            }

            return cb(null, user)
        } else {
            // No user found, create one
            const newUser = new User({
                name: profile.username,
               discordId: profile.id
            })
            // No need for a password
            await newUser.save()

            return cb(null, newUser)
        }    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return cb(err)
    }
}));
```

I need to export it to use the data from the `profile` object

Comment: I think you messed up the tags, there's no import for the `discord.js` module

Comment: okay but how can i export the profile object from this ?